# Join dataset and sql server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, dataset

I have a `dataset object` in **C# (SSIS package)** containing about **40000 rows** and `SQL table` containing about `50000000 rows`. I want to `join` these tables on their **IDs**.

I can't load the `SQL table` in C# as its too big, also, I don't have a permission on that server to create table (for cloning the object from **C#**).

Is there any way that I can join object and table?

Does C# or SSIS package support this kind of solution?

Comment: Only way left is to load records in chunks, join them, joined result save on disk ro somewhere else, dispose old records and read new ones.

Comment: The standard (and fast) ETL solution is to load the dataset into the database into a staging table, add proper indexes and join the two tables there. Otherwise you'll have to perform 40K lookups to find and pull matching rows from the database from any row in the  dataset

Comment: Does the user have permission to create a #temporary table in the database?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. User only has permissions on reading.

Comment: Then how complicated is the join between them?  If you only need certain ID's then you could select from the table with a big `IN` with all the required ID's.  If it's more complicated maybe something via a table variable...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do in SSIS.
Below are some scenarios to do it. Key question - do you have 1-many match or many-many match

### Alternative 1 - you need to match all rows of SQL Table refers to C# table (1 SQL table row matches 0 or 1 C# table rows).

High level view on the approach:

1. Create a dataset object with data and store it in SSIS Object type variable. Script Task will do it.
2. In DataFlow Script Source - read rows from the variable and write it to Cache Destination, persist into Cache file.
3. On the next Data Flow - read SQL table with OLEDB, and perform join with Lookup transformation, where Lookup uses Cache file created on step 2 as reference. You can add columns from Cache table as you wish.
4. The destination of the last Data Flow is up to you

Comments and samples:
Before entering code in Script Source -- add Output and specify output columns with its names and data types.
Script code for reading data from DataSet variable:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
#endregion

// Add in the appropriate namespaces
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        // Set up the DataAdapter to extract the data, and the DataTable object to capture those results
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Copy DataTable from DataSet
        dt = Variables.vResults.DataTable["dtName"];

        // Since we know the column metadata at design time, we simply need to iterate over each row in
        //  the DataTable, creating a new row in our Data Flow buffer for each
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            // Create a new, empty row in the output buffer
            SalesOutputBuffer.AddRow();

            // Now populate the columns - here are sample names, 
            // have to define it before as columns in Script Source Output
            SalesOutputBuffer.PurchOrderID = int.Parse(dr["PurchOrderID"].ToString());
            SalesOutputBuffer.RevisionNumber = int.Parse(dr["RevisionNumber"].ToString());
            SalesOutputBuffer.CreateDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["CreateDate"].ToString());
            SalesOutputBuffer.TotalDue = decimal.Parse(dr["TotalDue"].ToString());
        } 
    }
}
```

### Alternative 2. You want to match all rows of C# DataSet to SQL Table (1 C# table row matches 0 or 1 SQL Table rows)

High level view on the approach:

1. Create a dataset object with data and store it in SSIS Object type variable. Script Task will do it.
2. In DataFlow Script Source - read rows from the variable.
3. Then - create a Lookup with **Partial Cache** and define SQL query to your table. You can create a **No Cache** Lookup if IDs in C# table are unique. Define match condition and columns needed from SQL Table.
4. Save result at some Destination

### Bad Alternative - 1-many match with row multiplication

Example - row from C# table can match several SQL table rows and you have to output several rows in this case.

High level view on the approach:

1. Create a dataset object with data and store it in SSIS Object type variable. Script Task will do it.
2. In DataFlow Script Source - read rows from the variable. Sort it by ID.
3. Ad another Data Source where reading SQL Table, ordered by ID in the same direction.
4. Do a SSIS Merge Join
5. Save results to some destination

The bad thing about this scenario is that it may require a lot of RAM to do Sort and Merge Join transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Ferdipux's approach is good one and less complicated than what lies below. The tradeoff between their solution and this is performance versus complexity. In the approach outlined by Ferdipux, you'll have to pull all 50 million rows from your source table into the data flow just to identify whether you have a match.

The approach I propose is to

1. Load your dataset into a temporary table. You might not be able to create a permanent table but temporary objects should not be an issue
2. Rewrite your source query to incorporate the temporary table.

Now the database engine can efficiently extract the source data with minimal impact.

## Technical bits

Execute SQL Task (create temp table)
-> Data Flow Task (populate temp table
-> Data Flow Task (extract from big table)

In your connection manager to Source1, change the property for RetainSameConnection to True. This will ensure our temporary table does not go out of scope during execution.

### Execute SQL Task

Create a global temporary table when the package begins.

During development, you will need to open a connection and run the supplied code and KEEP THE CONNECTION OPEN. This is as simple as running the query in SSMS and not closing the application.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##SO_59281633') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##SO_59281633;
END
-- Create global temporary table 
CREATE TABLE ##SO_59281633
(
    SomeKey int NOT NULL
,   AValue varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

### Data Flow Task (populate temp table)

Use the approach outlined by Ferdipux but also you need to specify on the Data Flow's properties that `DelayValidation = True`

Validation happens when the package is opened for editing and when it begins execution. During normal execution, the temporary table won't exist until the previous task has executed so specifying Delay Validation means this task will not validate until it is time for it to start - as opposed to the package.

If you're comfortable with .net, you can replace this step by using a Script Task and then use an ADO.NET/OLE DB connection and command objects to load the temporary table.

### Data Flow Task (extract from big table)

You will again need to specify DelayValidation = True here as the source query will rely on a temporary object.

The source for your OLE DB Source will be changed from Table to Query and then specify your query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.BigTable AS BT INNER JOIN ##SO_59281633 AS SO ON SO.SomeKey = BT.SomeKey;
```